# Tweepy stream filter only following one filter

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I have Python code that looks like the following:

```
stream.filter(follow=[twitter_id], track=[hashtag_to_track], threaded=True)
```

I need it to follow a certain user (myself) and get Tweets live containing a certain hashtag. `twitter_id` is a string that contains the numerical user ID of a user and `hashtag_to_track` is a string that contains the hashtag to track. However, this code is not working. When I include both items in the filter it is getting all Tweets including the hashtag not just specific Tweets from the user. How can I restrict this to get only the Tweets from the user? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The track, follow, and locations fields should be considered to be combined with an OR operator. `track=foo&follow=1234` returns Tweets matching "foo" OR created by user 1234.

From the the Twitter API documentation for the [POST statuses/filter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter) endpoint that [`Stream.filter`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.0/stream.html#tweepy.Stream.filter) uses.

You'll have to manually filter it yourself if you want to filter by both user and keyword.